# Angularjs md-autocomplete with profile pictures

Tags: angularjs, md-autocomplete

I have a search bar in the top my page for searching profiles.
I would like to have an autocompletion feature like in facebook or linkedin.
I'm using angularjs in the front.

I need to show records of the found profiles with their images alongside with their full names.

How can I set the images of the found profiles in the md-items of md-autocomplete (is that possible at all)?
Is there a better way for such autocompletion without re-inventing the whole wheel, except the md-autocopmlete?

Thanks

Comment: yes its possible, see `Custom template` example on this link https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can. use `md-icon` to add an icon to your autocomplete result.

```
<md-autocomplete class="no-float" flex md-no-cache="noCache" md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in vm.querySearch(searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-floating-label="Project">
    <md-item-template>
        <span class="item-title">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="{{item.image}}"></md-icon> 
        </span>
        <span class="item-metadata">
            <span class="item-metastat">
                <strong>{{item.email}}</strong>
            </span>
        </span>
    </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much

Comment: @Shimon Topach nice !! make sure to check as right answer if this helped  :D

Comment: I did but because of the low reputation it's not visible yet. I'm trying to gain some